# Three.js Terrain/ Javascript Terrain Editor

Tags: three.js

I think I simply lack some keywords here...

I would like to create a 3D terrain editor for Javascript.

Basically saving the Terrains vertexes and coordinates of the Objects placed.

Can I get a little push in the right direction? :)

(Right now the ground is FLAT.. rather boring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could take a look at this terrain editor which uses three.js https://github.com/qiao/fractal-terrain-generator